How to find the generator matrix for the quotient group $C/C^{⟂}$ using a list of coset representatives of $C^{⟂}$ in $C$?
$C$ is the $[6,5,2]$ classical binary code.
I am trying to find the generator matrix for the quotient group $C/C^{⟂}$ from the list of coset representatives of $C^{⟂}$ in $C$.
My question refers to the workings on page 8 of the following paper.
My issue is that I cannot figure out how they found that the generator matrix for the quotient group $C/C^{⟂}$ is: $$G_{C/C^{⟂}}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

My attempt:
I found the parity check matrix $H=[1,1,1,1,1,1]$ from the dimensions of the code ($d-1=2-1=1$ linearly independent columns,$H$ of dimension $(n-k) \times n = 1 \times 6$). I then used the fact that $H$ was in standard form $H = [-A^{T}|I_{n-k}]$ to find the generator matrix $G$ in standard form $$G=[I_{k}|A]= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$ This is equivalent to the generator matrix $G_{C} = \begin{bmatrix} H_{C} \\
G_{C/C^{⟂}}
\end{bmatrix}$ given in the paper.
I am then able to get all of the $32$ codewords by finding the linear combinations of the rows of this generator matrix.
I then added each of the codewords to $C^{⟂}=((0,0,0,0,0,0),(1,1,1,1,1,1))$ to obtain the $16$ cosets, i.e. the 16 members of $C/C^{⟂}$. Note that each coset consists of $2$ vectors.
I then thought that I would just row reduce the vectors in $C/C^{⟂}$ and the result would be the generator matrix $G_{C/C^{⟂}}$. However, this did not work. Instead I got the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$ which is NOT equivalent to the matrix $G_{C/C^{⟂}}$ given in the paper.
My potential mistake is this: each coset consists of $2$ vectors, I was ignoring this. I put all of the vectors of the cosets into a list of $16$ vectors, each row containing $2$ vectors of length $6$. Then I flattened this into a list of $32$ vectors and then row reduced that. I think that was my mistake however, I am not sure how else to go about finding the generator matrix $G_{C/C^{⟂}}$ from the cosets representatives?

$C/C^\perp$ is not a (classical) code, so I find the title question a bit strange. Was this not explained to you already in your previous question.

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

@JyrkiLahtonen Apologies, I did not pick up on the fact that it was not a code. I understand that $C^{⊥}$ is a code and then $C/C^{⊥}$ consists of the distinct results of the codewords of $C$ added to $C^{⊥}$ . However, I had thought that these coset representatives constituted a new code (which obviously is incorrect). Is it because you cannot have a code in which each codeword consists of $2$ vectors?
I am still a little lost on how to create a generator matrix from the coset representatives of $C/C^{⊥}$, with the new understanding that it is not itself a code.

@Shaun question edited so as not to rely on picture of text. Thank you.

You do get a code by selecting the coset representatives carefully in such a way that the representatives form a subspace $V$. When that holds, you get a direct sum decomposition of vector spaces $C^\perp=V\oplus C$, but I would not denote any such $V$ by $C^\perp/C$. That feels very misleading, and the choice of $V$ is not unique! One way of achieving that is to always use a representative that has a zero at the last position, and that particular $V$ seems to have a generator matrix like the one you described. But we could equally well select the representative that has a zero at 4th position
